# <Swig Object of type 'Array< float > *

Tags: python, c++, swig

I'm using **SWIG** to wrap a piece of **C++** code to use it from **Python**.

Let's say I have an "*Array< T >*" user-defined class in C++ and I want to compute this line of code from Python:

```
myArray = MySWIGModule.getObject().myArray
```

where the method "*getObject()*" returns a class "Object" containing (amongst other things) an attribute "myArray" of type "*Array< float >*".

When I want to print the content or type of **myArray**, I get this:

```
<Swig Object of type 'Array< float > *
```

But what I would like to obtain is something like:

```
<class 'MySWIGModule.FloatArray'>
```

I tried with many different solutions without success. Do you know how to achieve this result? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
%template(FloatArray) Array<float>
```

to have SWIG [use that name in the interface](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_nn30).  That should be just about perfect with wrapper classes enabled; however, if it’s actually a pointer, SWIG might still use the template name.

Also, be careful of lifetime issues: it’s easy to get a pointer to part of an object that gets destroyed when the Python reference to it is dropped.